# Linked DB2 Table not accepting Date Criteria in MSAccess Query

Tags: ms-access, db2

I've been tasked with converting one of our old Access queries from pointing to SQL Server to point to DB2. The query is essentially the same outside of it pointing to 3 new linked **DB2** views.

The query  has 4 criteria in it. 3 of the 4 are either string or number columns (those work fine). The issue I am running into is for the 4th field which is a Date field.

Anytime I try to run the query with any date Criteria like `> #2017/10/27#` in the date field, it doesn't work and I get this strange message:

[image: Query Reserved Error]

What makes this even more strange is when I change the criteria to a **parameter** to prompt for a date input, IT WORKS. I would appreciate any help or work-around to solve this issue.

Note: I am on 64-bit Access

Comment: If the Db2 column-datatype is DATE or TIMESTAMP then you need to take care with the date literal values. Try using ISO format YYYY-MM-DD for date values.

Comment: Try with a string: `> "2017/10/27"`.

Comment: @Gustav When I try what you suggested, it automatically changes the format back to MM/DD/YYYY. I even changed it in SQL View, but it gave me the same error as in my post.

Comment: @mao When I tried using the literal, it gives me "Data type mismatch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My machine is on 64-Bit, but after testing the Access Database query on 32-Bit, it works now.